# access kubernetes services from another region in Google cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a kubernetes cluster in Google Cloud, and the machines of the cluster are in europe-west1-c.
Now I have a new machine (linux with tomcat) in europe-west4-a but when I try to get to the services exposed in kubernetes I cannot reach them.
Is there any way I can reach this server from different regions/zones?

Comment: what is the error you are getting , how are your services exposed in k8s cluster.

Comment: Which IP are you trying to reach, the public or the private. If it's the private, are you in the same VPC (even if you aren't in the same subnet, because you aren't in the same region)?

Comment: IPs are private. They all are in the same VPC, but it is an OLD one. It seems there is an OLD kind of VPC which has no subnets, and the new one in which I can see a subnet per region. But all my instances and the cluster is in the Old VPC, which range is 10.240.0.0/16. All my virtual instances and the services exposed by the cluster fill in that range.

Comment: All nodes in a private cluster are created without a public IP; they have limited access to Google APIs and services. To provide outbound internet access for your private nodes, you can use Cloud NAT or you can manage your own NAT gateway. To allow nodes to communicate with Google APIs and services, enable Private Google Access on your subnet. [1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#req_res_lim